# Is calling a function considered a context switching?

Tags: c++, c, function, context-switch

When I call a function as below

```
void main(void){
    Function();
}
```

Is it considered context switching because I save registers before go to the function ?

Comment: This shouldn't have been migrated, it's a question about the definition of terms as used in theoretical computer science discussions, not a question about behavior.

Comment: This is more helpful as an open question: if I think of a function call as a context switch, what would that mean, and what may be gathered from thinking about it this way?

Comment: Context switch is a standardized term. It refers to when the OS switches focus from one process to another, nothing else. It has nothing to do with the internals of that process.

Comment: @BenVoigt Agree completely, and it IMHO reflects in the answers given being rather inaccurate from a CS standpoint...

Comment: regarding: `void main(void){`  There are only two valid signatures for `main()` they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`.  Notice they both have a return type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: @user3629249 just to be doubly precise: the implementation *may* allow for additional signatures, such as returning void. Also, if we aren't in a hosted environment this doesn't matter. But these are details, you're right.

Comment: @larkey, None the less, the C language standard only specifies the two signatures for `main()`

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, but others *might* be valid. In particular 5.1.2.2.1, paragraph 1 states 'It [the main function] shall be defined [...] or in some other implementation-defined manner.' But yes, one shouldn't write main like that (usually), I just wanted to be 'complete'.

Answer (score 8):

No, context switch occurs **when the kernel swaps a process**. calling a **user space function** will leave you inside the same process, and therefore wont be context switch. calling a **kernel function** however, requires an operation from the kernel and therefore it is a context switch to the kernel.

Comment: when a function is called, some registers are kept as-is but others are copied to the **program stack**

Comment: It also occurs when switching from user to kernel mode and back, as when executing a system call.

Comment: Context in OS usually refers to the registers and the program stack, this in a broader sense would also include the page table entries. When calling another function none of these are swapped with another context. While doing a syscall kernel context is brought in even when swtiching between threads there is a context switch.

Comment: Threads are "mini processes" so yea there would be context switch in that case (although it has nothing to do with calling functions)

Comment: Swapping is a different thing altogether and even kernel functions usually doesn't leave the processes address space. With threading you only need to switch between CPU registers which can be considered a context switch or not.

Comment: @Anirudh Well, a syscall doesn't make backing up all registers necessary, you have a calling convention just as with normal functions. You need to switch modes though, and sometimes the page table entries.

Comment: Those who downvote this answer, can you please explain what it bothering you? (so i can fix it appropriately)? thx :)

Comment: @larkey thanks for filling this gap in my understanding. Yes, this seems to OS dependent, some just raise the protection level and are able to handle this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#Processor_mode_and_context_switching

Answer (score 3):

Before we ask ourselves whether we consider this "context switch", we should clear up what it means, or rather what it *can* mean.

When we are talking about the OS kernel and processes, we can "switch" between multiple things:

1. Privilege levels/Rings/Modes
2. CPU Register Set
3. Virtual Memory Areas

Often, not just one of these happens alone. A *mode switch* is something that is rather frequent, supervisor calls / exceptions or hardware interrupts (e.g. a timer for scheduling or an external device) necessarily trigger these. In almost every scenario we need to acquire higher privileges to actually "do something".

Storing *all* of the CPUs registers is needed when we have some kind of asynchronous interruption of the execution. This is not *necessarily needed* for supervisor calls, as there we can define a calling-convention between the caller and the callee, which registers who is responsible to backup before executing the instruction<sup>1</sup>. This is simply not possible with hardware interrupts, as we do not know when they will trigger: How should a process be able to foresee that it will be interrupted in the next *t* nanoseconds and has to backup all used registers?

A switch between virtual memory areas is needed when we e.g. switch between processes (every process has their own address space) or between a process and the kernel address space (and so does the kernel). However, it's often not needed for supervisor calls as these are usually mapped into the processes address space and thus only execute with higher privilege (kernel mode) without "leaving the process" (processes' address space).<sup>2</sup>

While switches between privilege levels are rather cheap (performance wise), switching out the complete CPU register set is already quite expensive. However, unloading the complete page table, flushing the TLB etc. is the most expensive and we try to keep this down as much as possible. This is also a reason why threads are far more performant (in general) than processes: Switching between them only needs a switch between CPU registers (and, depending on the implementation, a short mode switch) but not a switch between address spaces!

When we read about "context switch" in literature, it's unfortunately not always clear what of these three, or which combination, is actually referred to as "switching the context". From what I can gather, the term comes from a very simplified machine model that has no distinction between interrupts, exceptions / supervisor calls, nor between switching CPU registers or address spaces. In this model we only see "the kernel [mode/space/...]" and "the user [mode/space/...]" and any switch between these is considered a "context switch".

Fortunately, your posted scenario does not fit into *any* of these switches as it is a synchronous, unprivileged, function call within the same address space, thus not needing any switch but a simple calling convention that only saves those registers that need saving suffices.

---

<sup>1</sup> But this might have security implications, as correctly pointed out by @BenVoigt.  This is no issue for calls like `gettimeofday()` (cf. [this LWN.net article](https://lwn.net/Articles/615809/)), but in other cases this might result into spilling confidential data to the user process.

<sup>2</sup> Some microkernel designs dispatch a *process* which actually handles the supervisor call implementation, thus making a switch to this processes address space necessary.

Comment: "This is not the case for supervisor calls, as there we can define a calling-convention between the caller and the callee, which registers who is responsible to backup before executing the instruction."  Do that, and now you have an exposure of protected data type attack (see for example Heartbleed).  The supervisor needs to restore any the registers it used which might contain privileged data and not rely on the caller to do so.  Generally to be safe that means that the syscall should restore all that were used in any way

Comment: Generally though this is a far more useful answer, particularly for CS discussions and literature, than the other answers.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, I rephrased that part to add the nod wrt. to security!

Answer (score 0):

## Context Switching?

When we multitask, what we really do is constantly switch from one task to another. That is what context switching is.

The term originates from computer science. A CPU running multi-threaded processes temporarily puts on hold an execution of a given thread while running another one.

**Calling a function does not switch processes except for kernel processes**